# table can be searched instead of tab----the search function in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I built my docs locally using Sphinx and it contains one or two articles to test.

[image]

[image]

When I search for "tab", there are no search results, but I expected it to match "table".  When I search for "table", there are two search results.  Why are there no search results when I search for "tab"?

Answer (score 0):

The default Sphinx search returns only exact matches, as one can see in the following lines of the [source code](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/themes/basic/static/searchtools.js_t#L393):

```
// perform the search on the required terms
for (i = 0; i < searchterms.length; i++) {
  var word = searchterms[i];
  var files = [];
  var _o = [
    {files: terms[word], score: Scorer.term},
    {files: titleterms[word], score: Scorer.title}
  ];
  ...
}
```

The search takes a search term and checks if it is a key in the search index (JSON object, generated during build time). If this is the case, it retrieves further information about the files (and lines) that contain the term.
To change this, you need to extend the default Sphinx search to first check if your search term is a *fuzzy* (approximate) match to any of the terms the search index lists and then feed all matches as "terms" into the search function.

To my knowledge there is no open source solution/Sphinx theme available that already does this for you.